# How to redirect http request to https on websphere application server

Tags: ssl, websphere

I am trying to automatically redirect http request to https on websphere application server.

I found a solution for weblogic here - http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=2019

I was wondering if there is any thing similar for websphere where in I can just change the web.xml and do something in admin console.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended by IBM to use always a proper reverse proxying web server (IHS, Apache, etc) in front of WAS. The reason is that the integrated web server that is attached to the web transport chain really doesn't offer anything besides the most basic functionalities.

Generally what your are asking for should be done with the IHS/Apache and you want to do something like

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```